# CSS Text Padding in li menu not working

Tags: css, html-lists, padding

I am currently creating a UL menu, and I'm having some difficulties. Whenever I am trying to move down the text in the LI it is making the div bigger.

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="accordion"> 
        <li class="files">
                <a href="#one">Dashboard<span>0</span></a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

CSS Code:

```
.accordion li > a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 110px;
        padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
        height: 50px !important;
        color: #C8C8C8;
        font: bold 12px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
}
```

So whenever I change the padding to this:

padding: 5px 20px 0 50px;

It makes the div 55px in height, when it should be 50px. Hope someone can help me with this! Thank you.

Comment: You are adding 5px on the top which is added to the height unless you use css `box-sizing`. http://learnlayout.com/box-sizing.html Also to get the text align vertically in the middle you can use `line-height`.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Well, I added this and it worked. display:inline-block;

Comment: No problem I am adding an answer and jsfiddle to show box-sizing/line-height. If you want you can mark it as accepted or whatever that is fine with me. :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how `box-sizing`/`padding` and `line-height` work. My personal opinion is that line-height is the best option and a lot more easy to calc.

*They can be used together for a truly awesome combo!*

**Line-height/Padding CSS**

```
.lH {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background: #ff7200;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

**Box-sizing CSS**

```
.bS {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background: mediumSeaGreen;
  padding: 12px 0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p6BCF/1/)